# Unexpected result when checking network reachability

Tags: iphone

In my app I implemented the code for network reachability. 
This is my code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
// Test for internet.
gotInternet = [self checkInternet];
if (gotInternet == NO) {
    // No Internet.
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"The internet is down" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
else {
    NSLog(@"I do have internet");
}

}


-(BOOL)checkInternet {
//Test for Internet Connection
NSLog(@"——–");
NSLog(@"Testing Internet Connectivity");
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"https://mobile.areafinancial.com/cutechservice/cutechwebservice.asmx"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
BOOL internet;
if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)) {
    internet = NO;
} else {
    internet = YES;
}
return internet;
}
```

This code returns me gotInternet = NO; Actually WiFi is enabled. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered logging the value of `internetStatus` to see what it actually is?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",internetStatus); This gives me null.

Comment: That syntax will always puzzle me... `if (test) { return YES; } else { return NO; }` — why not just `return test` ? (or the reverse, considering you return NO if your test succeeds)

Comment: @Cyrille There is no problem with syntax. If you have any other alternative to implement same functionality than please suggest.

Comment: I didn't say there was a problem. I'm just affirming that a clean syntax may prevent you from doing mistakes. Whatever your current problem is, I'm giving you a general advice of readability and simplicity. `if (isSimple) return YES; else return NO` --> `return isSimple`.

Comment: @Cyrille the problem with your code is you have no idea about the TYPE of the return value, is your test returning a BOOL or a long, unsigned long, what if BOOL is defined as '1 == TRUE, anything else == FALSE', your test would fail. Obviously bool is defined as 0 = FALSE anything else = TRUE, but it does't *HAVE* to be that way.

Comment: @Tony In this case, he could have written `return (status == ReachableViaWifi || status == ReachableViaWWAN)` which returns a perfectly valid BOOL, is much more concise and readable. Equality tests are easier to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are testing a FULL URL  not a HOST NAME.....

```
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"mobile.areafinancial.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Comment: Further more, I'd suggest heading over to http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24 to get his version of the Reachability code. as then you can do something as simple as: [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"mobile.areafinancial.com"] isReachable];

Answer (score -1):

try this I have modified your code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
// Test for internet.
//gotInternet = [self checkInternet];
if (![self checkInternet]) {
    // No Internet.
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"The internet is down" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
else {
    NSLog(@"I do have internet");
}

}


-(BOOL)checkInternet {
//Test for Internet Connection
NSLog(@"——–");
NSLog(@"Testing Internet Connectivity");
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"https://mobile.areafinancial.com/cutechservice/cutechwebservice.asmx"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
BOOL internet;
if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)) {
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
//return internet;
}
```

Comment: And you missed the obvious mistake.